# Solution near a Brillouin-zone boundary, central equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

First of all, I'm using ["Introduction to Solid-State Physics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Solid_State_Physics) by Charles Kittel, 8th edition.

Let's say that the distance between two atoms are a, this would mean that:

$G_0=\frac {2 \pi}{a}$, at the zone boundary we would then have $k=\frac {G_0}{2}=\frac {\pi}{a}$. Kittel is then claiming that only $C(\frac{G}{2})$ and $C(\frac{-G}{2})$ is the two most important coefficients in the so-called central equation.

My first question is therefore, why is it so self-explained that only these two coefficients will be of interest?

Second, the central equation, according to Kittel, with $k=\frac{G}{2}$ takes the form:

$(\lambda -\epsilon)C(\frac{G}{2}) + UC(\frac{-G}{2})=0$

This equation isn't weird, but then he says that the other equation takes the form, with $k=\frac{G}{2}$:
$(\lambda - \epsilon)C(\frac{-G}{2} + UC(\frac{G}{2})=0$

When I try to put in $k=\frac{G}{2}$: I'm not getting that at all, what am I doing wrong?

The central-equation is given as:
$(\lambda - \epsilon)C(K) + \sum U_G C(K-G)=0$

Comment: What exactly is the central equation? What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Ive edited so that the central-equation is at the bottom, I try to use the central-equation to calculate the solution near a brillouin-zone boundary

Comment: OK. That helps. But what physically are you trying to calculate? What are $C$, $\lambda$, $\epsilon$, etc?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to understand the coefficients  that Kittel says are "obvious" to be there, I cant really understand what the physical interpretation of them are.

Comment: I do not have a copy of Kittle in front of me, and most people trying to answer this question will not either. You are far more likely to get a helpful answer if you make your question self contained.